# PHP ActiveRecord: Перехват Exceptions

Tags: activerecord, исключения, php

Всем привет.

Для одного проекта использую известную ORM [PHP-ActiveRecord](http://phpactiverecord.org).

Успешно подключил, заработало. Но есть одно большое НО. 
При всех ошибках и прочих эта либа выкидывает исключение, что не всегда приемлемо.

Например, мне нужно посмотреть:

```
$client = \Model\Client::find($someId);
```

Если пользователь есть, но мне возвращает конкретную модель, а если нет - то

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\RecordNotFound'
```

А мне нужно, допустим, продолжить код и выполнить что-то другое в вызываемом методе. Но Exception мне не дает этого сделать. Писать try {..} catch ($e) {..} для каждого обращения к модели, сами понимаете, ерунда - теряется вся прелесть ORM.

установка set_exception_handler - вообще убийство, после выполнения callback - выполнение скрипта останавливается.

Как мне продолжить выполнение скрипта, даже если ORM выдал исключение? 
Как это возможно обойти? 
Если невозможно, то какую еще ORM можете посоветовать(только не Доктрину(:)?

Или я вообще не правильно ее использую?

P.S.: они бы еще вместо Exception die() вызывали бы ))

Answer (score 1):

Плюнул и поставил Eloquent ORM из Laravel4. Он работает как надо. При пустом результате - return null. Никаких Exceptions и прерываний работы программы. [Пример установки](http://www.slimframework.com/news/slim-and-laravel-eloquent-orm)

У меня не Slim, а самописный фреймворк, но не смотря на это он отлично пристроился.
Всем спасибо

Answer (score 0):

В руби это обходят примерно так:

```
$client = \Model\Client::find_by_id($someId);
```

или

```
$client = \Model\Client::find_all_by_id($someId);
```

Попробуйте, может и здесь сработает.

Comment: А что, в руби так же исключение кидается на find ?